# How to get current scroll position in WebView with help of javascript : MonoTouch?

Tags: javascript, uiwebview, xamarin.ios, scrollbar

I am populating html string to UIWebView, i want to scroll and take ScreenShots Programmatically, so i need current scroll position, with javascript or some other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

scrollY would give you the vertical scroll value..similarly scrollX would give you the value of the horizontal scroll..If you are looking to scroll using code have a look  at [scrollTo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.scrollTo) and [scrollBy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.scrollBy)

Comment: thanks, scrollTo i am already using and its working fine, its scrolling to given postion, But what i wanted was what is the current scroller position i got that by using

    window.pageYOffset;

Answer (score 0):

i found it, i am using following to get the current scroll postion directily from UIWebView in Monotouch ..

```
float currentScrollerPosition = Convert.ToInt32 (WebView1.EvaluateJavascript    (@"window.pageYOffset;"));
```